# Bash program simple print

Tags: windows, bash

Bash program to print

```sh
a = 1
b = 2
pause
if [ a < b]
    then
        echo "in the if command"
        pause
```

i execute the file but the program stop before the if and when i skip the pause se program close
idk why the program stop before if

Comment: PLease use something like https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check for common bash errors

Comment: 1) No space around `a = 1` 2) Missing space after `[ a < b]`. 3) `pause`?

Comment: i correct the first two tip but doesn't work again, for the 3 question pause stop the program and when u click enter the program coninue                                              
a=1
b=2
pause
if [ a < b ]
 then
  echo "in the if command"
  pause

Comment: It's `if [ a < b ]; then echo "in if command; fi`. In bash you close the `if` with `fi`. Also, the `]` can not touch the `b`. Also also, what does "pause" do? Because it's a command I don't have. Also also also, every beginner tutorial shows how this works. It's a very basic script.

Comment: i do what u did but i have the follow error:  a and b are not recognise as command  internal or extarnal, a program that can be execute or a bach file

Comment: the pause command sry is not correct i use it in different lan prog and i think it can be use but don't work